# Where the ICM20948 DMP memory is stored?

Tags: sensor, signal-processing, memory, imu

In Invensense ICM20948 motion sensor
[they mention](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/AN-000146-v2.0-TDK_Migration_MPU_9250toICM-20948.pdf)

*The DMP in ICM-20948, therefore, has higher memory for code storage
Hence, the AP/MCU must accommodate higher memory required to hold the DMP image
AP/MCU must be able to store more code to accommodate expanded DMP code size. However, if Application does not use DMP functions, then this code size can be avoided.*

DMP code size 16kB

Does it means if Arduino nano is used to get data from this sensor, and DMP is being used, Arduino nano has to store memory 16kB extra related to DMP of ICM20948 sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, but only in code size. RAM usage should stay the same, excluding the buffer used when uploading the data to the ICM, which shouldn't be more than 8 bytes.

Comment: @Flip further clarification,  does DMP code that runs on Arduino only sending back sensor offsets back to the sensor ic? and complete DMP library (fusion) is running on Arduino nano memory?